# Feedzirra in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

I am trying to get feedzirra running on rails 3, I tried by some methods I have found on the internet.

This is in my gemfile:

```
source 'http://gems.github.com'

gem 'loofah', '1.0.0.beta.1'
group :after_initialize do
    gem 'pauldix-feedzirra'
end
```

And i've out this after bundle.setup in root.rb

```
Bundler.require :after_initialize
```

And this is the code in my model (movie.rb)

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.import_from_feed
    feed = Feedzirra::Feed.fetch_and_parse("url-to.xml")
    add_entries(feed.entries)
  end

  private

  def self.add_entries(entries)
    entries.each do |entry|
      unless exists? :guid => entry.id
        create!(
          :title        => entry.title,
          :synopsis     => entry.synopsis,
          :cover        => entry.cover,
          :duration     => entry.duration,
          :channel      => entry.channel,
          :imdb_rating  => entry.imdb_rating,
          :imdb_votes   => entry.imdb_votes,
          :imdb_id      => entry.imdb_votes
        )
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I try to run the import_from_feed function from the console and I keep getting this error:

```
>> Movie.import_from_feed
NameError: uninitialized constant Movie::Feedzirra
    from /Users/myname/Ruby/appname/app/models/movie.rb:3:in `import_from_feed'
    from (irb):1
```

Can someone help me out? Been trying for ages now!

Answer (score 6):

Two things:

1. Just add the gem, not under `:after_initialize`
2. Use the `feedzirra` gem, not the old `pauldix-feedzirra` one.